# Tkinter Python - How to delete blank in label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have an issue with a label on tkinter. I would like to know if it's possible to "occupy space", when I insert long text my label become huge and I have a lot of blank around my text. Is it possible to delete this blank ?

```
action=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_right, width=400, height=150, text="", justify=tkinter.LEFT,  text_font=("Roboto Medium", -10), fg_color="white")
action.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=15, pady=15,  sticky='')
```

[Label from custom tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0oKz.png)

Here the code to reproduct what happen :

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *

class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    WIDTH = 850
    HEIGHT = 620

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window (you can also use normal tkinter.Tk window)
app.geometry(f"{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}")#taille de la fenetre graphique
app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame_right = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe", padx=20, pady=20)
# configure grid layout (3x7)
frame_right.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=1)
frame_right.rowconfigure(7, weight=10)
frame_right.columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
frame_right.columnconfigure(2, weight=0)

action=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_right, width=400, height=150, text="", justify="center",  text_font=("Roboto Medium", -10), fg_color="white")
action.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=15, pady=15, sticky="n")
action.configure(text="CustomTkinter is a python UI-library based on Tkinter, which provides new, modern and fully customizable widgets.\nThey are created and used like normal Tkinter widgets and can also be used in combination with normal Tkinter")

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve]. These two lines of code are not sufficient to understand the problem.

Comment: Hello @BryanOakley, I edited my post with a code to reproduct it

Answer (score 0):

You've given an explicit width and height to the label, so tkinter is trying to honor that size. Since your text doesn't fill the space, the extra space is going to appear blank.

If you remove `width=400, height=150,` from where you create the label, the label will be just big enough to fit the text.

The following screenshot shows what I get when I remove the explicit width and height:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your method, but still have huge blank on both side

Comment: I'm now trying to loop when I have 40 character I force a line break

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my problem, I replaced this

```
frame_right.columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
frame_right.columnconfigure(2, weight=0)
```

by this :

```
frame_right.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_right.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
```